# Cisco DDR2200 Port Forwarding

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, port, forwarding

My brother has a server in his garage and has been using it to serve is own little website for a while now (about a year and a half or two). I've been the one managing it, but he recently changed ISPs and the website is no longer accessible. I've set up port forwarding in the router, but no luck. The router is from the ISP, and the internet goes directly into the router and the server is connected directly to the router. This is the same setup as before except for the new router, and the server is now connected wirelessly (this is due to the ISP setting up the router in the wrong room in the house. my brother wasn't home when they did it :/ )

Apache is running fine on the server (I can access the site locally with the LAN ip address). If I try to access the website using the public IP address from within the LAN, I get sent to the router configuration page, as if I typed in the router IP address (although, this may have to do with the fact that I'm trying to access it from within the LAN).

If I try to access the site from another connection (I'm using my phones internet at the moment, as I don't have another outside connection to test from), I get a 502 Bad Gateway response. I am not getting any errors or access logs from Apache on the server, and a port checking website tells me the port is closed (http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/).

We've been trying to get this working for a while now with no luck. I can't find what has changed/went wrong anywhere. If anyone has any ideas on how to rectify this, I would greatly appreciate it. Aside from the website being down, this is just plain frustrating.

The server is running Windows Server Enterprise.

Comment: Some ISPs block ports (coming in), so there is a chance that the ISP is the one hindering it and not anything on your end.  You could try an alternative port, such as 8080 and see if it's a port issue through the ISP.  Of course, any linking/dns service you have would need to be updated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the router's web-based administration is listening on port 80, it probably can't also forward port 80. You can forward a different port or move the administration to a different port. If this is DSL, just replace the router (the ones ISPs provide are usually junk). If it's cable or fiber, you probably don't have that choice.

Comment: You were right. I tried 8080 (as suggested in a comment above), but the modem appears to be using it for remote admin access to the router setup. I settled for a nice random 35212. I didn't find anything that used it on Google, so I figured it would work. Thanks for the quick help!